# Register ResourceLocator with Autofac for WPF Application.Current

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, autofac

So to get around unit testing Application.Current, I created a ResourceLocator referenced from [this](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/09/using-nunit-with-wpf/). This would, if I can figure out how to register it in Autofac, allow me to inject the resource which would allow me to unit test without the worry of Application.Current being null. My question is how can i register this locator in autofac without autofac actually creating a new instance of the app? The appliaction.current is already created for us so I don't want autofac injecting another instance of the Application into my viewmodels. Something like:

```
 container.RegisterType<ResourceLocator>().As<IResourceLocator>().SingleInstance();
```

Yes this will return a single instance but I think autofac will sill try to create an instance in the very beginning. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlooking the fact that requiring `Autofac` and `Application.Current` means you are *integration testing* and not *unit testing*, you can see from running this test that `Autofac` does not appear to generate a new value for `Application.Current`

```
[Test]
public void RegisterResolver()
{
    //Arrange
    Application expected = Application.Current;
    var mainBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    mainBuilder.RegisterType<ResourceLocator>()
        .As<IResourceLocator>()
        .SingleInstance();
    IContainer container = mainBuilder.Build();

    //Act
    IResourceLocator test1 = container.Resolve<IResourceLocator>();
    IResourceLocator test2 = container.Resolve<IResourceLocator>();

    //Assert
    Assert.That(test1, Is.EqualTo(test2));
    Assert.That((test1 as ResourceLocator).application, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    Assert.That((test2 as ResourceLocator).application, Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
```

However, if you do want more control you can use the `Register` method to define the initialiser for the instance you want to be used.

```
mainBuilder.Register(c => new ResourceLocator(Application.Current))
    .As<IResourceLocator>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: Hi Qujck, yes calling the register method through autofac was what I had wound up doing and it seems to be fine. On another note, "Overlooking the fact that requiring Autofac and Application.Current means you are integration testing and not unit testing" I'm not sure if I agree with you 100% on this. Basically I'm unit testing a method that is inside one my viewmodels and to get to it I have to take care of my dependencies first. To do this I can now create a FakeResourceLocator using autofac. At that point technically I haven't touched a database so its still considered a unit test.

Comment: @TMan it's clearly a (sometime inflammatory) subjective issue but IMO `Autofac` is as much an external dependency as a database (although obviously not as slow!). A test that includes correctly configuring an external dependency and testing *something* returned by an external dependency is on the cusp of the unit test/integration test divide.